# C# массив ключей и словарь через Linq

Tags: c#, linq, key

Есть массив ключей **"string[] keys"** и словарь **"Dictionary<string, double> dict**". Хочу методами Linq сделать словарь с пересечением по всем ключам из массива **"string[] keys"** в словаре **"Dictionary<string, double> dict"** . Если можно пример . Спасибо

Comment: `var result = dict.Where(x=>keys.Contains(x.Key));`

Comment: Благодарю . Очень помогли